# Cannot import binance-api-client into JavaFX Application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, binance-api-client

I have a JavaFX project.

Ive installed a dependency for the binance-api-client package.
Its in my dependencies folder

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.binance.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>binance-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, when I go to import it it.

```
import com.binance.client.*;
```

It says

```
  package com.binance.client is not visible
```

If I then follow the Netbeans advice to "Add Module to ModuleInfo".  I get this in the module info.

```
module com.mycompany.btrade {
   requires javafx.controls;
   requires javafx.fxml;
   requires binance.api.client;
   opens com.mycompany.btrade to javafx.fxml;
   exports com.mycompany.btrade;

}
```

However then when I run the program, it just crashes, with this error

```
java.lang.module.FindException: Module binance.api.client not found, required by com.mycompany.btrade
```

Why can't I seem to import this package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're trying to use binance-java-api, which is what you want if you're working solely with Java, or if there actually is some other package that exists called com.binance.sdk.

From the documentation I looked at, your dependency should read:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.binance.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>binance-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

That being said, I'm not certain if that versioning will still work if you make that change, but this would explain the error stating:

```
binance.api.client not found, required by com.mycompany.btrade
```

as it doesn't match the package described by the dependency.

Comment: I changed it to that, and now I get this error "Cannot invoke "java.lang.Throwable.getCause()" because "cause" is null"

Comment: Seems to be a case of JavaFX just not being able to use regular Java Packages?? I dont know enough about to Java to diagnose.  But if I start a Swing application from scratch, and import this, it works perfectly fine.   Its just when I start a JavaFX from scratch and import it the exact same way.  It just doesnt work.  (netbeans 12.3).  Im following the exact same steps in each app.  Swing works, JavaFX doesnt.  Is it teh folder structure or something?  Do I have to refer to it differently somehow??

Comment: I just removed module-info.java and suddenly this worked.  So....go figure?

Comment: If the dependency was met then I would say its more likely a matter of how you need to refer to it in the module-info. I would try changing it to read:
requires binance.client;
If their maven build matches their git repository, then that is likely how it is named.